# Laravel migrations completed but not always visible in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, vagrant

I am working with a team on a project in *laravel* and have to migrate the database with vagrant ssh using scotchbox. Using the php artisan migrate method in /var/www I can migrate the set up migrations. These will get migrated successfully.

When I log in using Sequel Pro or MySQLWorkbench, these tables appear in the database. But then they disappear, being invisible most of the time even whilst keeping the connection. Resetting, refreshing or tinkering with the migrations does not seem to fix the problem. I tried to add some records but upon loging in with my user it does not work, receiving this error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 651:
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'scotchbox.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = jos@jos.com limit 1)"

My tables can not be found even though they are migrated. Oddly, and I am not sure if it has anything to do with it, I sometimes get a "**FORBIDDEN**: you don't have permission to acces /page on this server" when being on any page. But nevertheless, I have a migration problem. Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: do you have something when you provision your VM that would delete the DB ?

Comment: I seem to lose connection even though my VM is always up and running. Tables / DB don't get deleted, they appear and disappear. I will try to start fresh with vagrant and such.

Comment: Possibly, multiple vagrants are running. Will experiment with this and try to solve.

Comment: but each of the VM run by those vagrant connect on the same DB or they each have a sql running on the VM ?

Comment: The issue was multiple VM's on the same IP. Resulting in the signal flaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was multiple VM's on the same IP. Resulting in the signal flaking and the database not always being found. The connection was there but not always the right one.

Comment: Good that you found a solution. Will you mark your answer as answered?